# Simple VBA code to open cells one after the other

Tags: vba, excel

How would an Excel VBA command look like that activates a cell for editing (like double-click), does nothing else, than jumps to the next cell, and so on to the end of the column?

Comment: Quickly have a read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Requests for code to be written without any attempt or effort from the person posting the question usually get ignored (and downvoted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want to do this? VBA doesn't have a keyword that represents entering into a cell. You can select the cell like this though:

```
Sub DoNotRun()
    Dim rng as range
    For Each rng In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A:A")
        rng.Select
    Next rng
End Sub
```

If you *really* need to simulate a double click -- Worksheets have a `_BeforeDoubleClick` event that might help